# How to watch Youtube fullscreen on one monitor of a dual-monitor display?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, display, multiple-monitors

How to watch Youtube fullscreen on one monitor of a dual-monitor display, in Linux?

If I do it in Google Chrome, as soon as I do anything at the other monitor, Chrome jumps back to normal window.

Edit: added that OS is Linux.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally I [stumbled upon a very easy solution](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/youtube-fullscreen-208200.html):

> - Go to a video on YouTube, in this example I am going to use http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6v2L2UGZJAM
> - Modify the link slightly (this works with ANY video on YouTube)
>
>   From: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6v2L2UGZJAM`
>     To: `http://www.youtube.com/v/6v2L2UGZJAM`
> - Enjoy your video!
>
> You can also press F11 if you want to toggle between fullscreen mode (in your browser, not the video itself) which will increase the size of the image slightly.

Comment: This is a perfectly good solution for windows as well.

Comment: Does not work for all videos, some of them return an error "This video contains content from ... . It is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch on YouTube".

Comment: Wow! Super cool solution for youtube + firefox 33.0 + ubuntu 14.04 here. No need for an add-on or strange hack.

Comment: This appears to not work at all anymore.  Gives me a 404 page.

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior of Flash in a browser, and you need to tweak Flash itself to work around the issue. I've had luck with FlashHacker in the past, and the dev now has a Chrome-specific version:

http://jmaxxz.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=94:drizzlychrome&catid=16:downloads&Itemid=32

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for Linux?

Comment: Nope it's designed for Windows only. I believe there are patches out there for Linux as well but I don't recall any off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

I use VLC for that. It can even load playlists (might need some extra scripts for that to work). Also it skips advertisments.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and enter youtube url.

also:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7284/youtube-keep-fullscreen-while-switching-to-other-app

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I use is to zoom in on the page (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> on a Mac).

Certainly not perfect but is doing a great job, allowing me to watch the Olympics on one monitor while working on another.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Firefox plugin that automatically changes all YouTube videos to HTML5 (converts them on the spot). HTML5 video doesn't break when I click somewhere else.

[YouTube Flash to HTML5](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-to-HTML5/)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution and suddenly reminded about [minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube) which does the job perfectly. Just enter unique video id or use the searcher.